# How to create a task or user story via the rest api

Tags: powershell, rest, azure-devops

I am trying to create a user story and task in Azure DevOps with this [RESTapi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)
There are multiple backlogs.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${type}?api-version=6.0
```

My code

```
function Set-pbiStuff {
    param
    ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string] $Organization,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string] $Project,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [hashtable] $Token
    )
  
    $Base = "https://dev.azure.com/$($organization)/$($project)/_apis/wit/workitems"
    $workItemType = 'task'
    $URL = "$($Base)/$($workItemType)?api-version=6.0"
    $Json = @(
        @{
            op    = 'add'
            path  = '/fields/System.Title'
            value = $workItemType
        }
    )
    
    $Body = (ConvertTo-Json $Json)
  
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod `
        -Method Post `
        -Uri $URL `
        -ContentType 'application/json' `
        -Body $Body `
        -Headers $Token
    Write-Host $URL
    Write-Host $response
}

$Token= @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN)")) }

$tt = Set-pbiStuff -Organization 'myOrganization' -Project 'myProject' -Token $Token

return $tt
```

But the response I get is that the page was not found.
What have I missed?

Comment: Most important question I have based on your post... Have you looked at the URL it's trying to call to (the value of the `$URL` parameter)? Also: why create the `$AzAuthHeader` outside of the function, but not pass it in as a parameter?

Comment: It was only missing in the example in the post, added it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the type `${type}` is incorrect in your script, the character `$` is missing.

Please try this:

```
$URL = "$($Base)/"+"$"+"$($workItemType)?api-version=6.0"
```

And the content type should be "`application/json-patch+json`"

Below script works for me : (PAT used for the test, you can change it back to `SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` if you run it in pipeline)

```
function Set-pbiStuff {
    param
    ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string] $Organization ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string] $Project ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string] $Token
    )
  
    $Base = "https://dev.azure.com/$($organization)/$($project)/_apis/wit/workitems"
    $workItemType = 'task'
    $URL = "$($Base)/"+"$"+"$($workItemType)?api-version=6.0"
    $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f '',$Token)))

    $Json = @(
        @{
            op    = 'add'
            path  = '/fields/System.Title'
            value = $workItemType
        }
    )
    
    $Body = (ConvertTo-Json $Json)
  
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod `
        -Method Post `
        -Uri $URL `
        -ContentType 'application/json-patch+json' `
        -Body $Body `
        -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
    Write-Host $URL
    Write-Host $response
}

$tt = Set-pbiStuff -Organization 'orgname' -Project 'ProjectName' -Token Tokenhere

return $tt
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call the API with a PATCH verb, see line two:

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod `
    -Method Patch `
    -Uri $URL `
    -ContentType 'application/json' `
    -Body $Body `
    -Headers $AzAuthHeader
```

The API endpoint is, like the documentation shows and you stated in your question, a POST endpoint.

Comment: I have changed to POST now but end up with response

Answer (score 0):

Try this URL:

```
$URL = "$($Base)/`$$($workItemType)?api-version=6.0"
```

Check this sample: https://arindamhazra.com/create-azure-devops-task-using-powershell/